# ordenar lista de dicionários por chave que contenha chave None

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso ordenar uma lista de dicionários por uma determinada chave quando dentro desses dicionários existe um com a chave `None`?

Exemplo:

```
mylist = [{'category': 'director'}, {'category': 'manager'}, {'category': None}]
mylist.sort() # causa erro porque não se pode comprar dict < dict

# causa erro porque não se pode comprar str < NoneType
result = sorted(mylist, key=lambda c: c['category'])
```

A ideia principal é sempre conseguir pegar o mais importante entre a lista com o seguinte nível de relevância:
`director > manager` e `manager > None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia é sempre comparar dados do mesmo tipo. A maneira mais fácil (e mais clara) é mapear os valores que você possui para valores inteiros e ordenar a lista conforme esses números.

```
PRIORIDADE = {
    'director': 1,
    'manager': 2
}
```

Assim, para ordenar, ao invés de usar o valor real, use o valor mapeado:

```
result = sorted(mylist, key=lambda c: PRIORIDADE.get(c['category'], 999))
```

Assim, qualquer valor que não possua uma prioridade definida, incluindo o `None`, será considerado 999, ficando ao final da lista.